# Pygame cant get events inside nested while loop

Tags: python, pygame, event-handling, nested-loops, infinite-loop

I've looked at a couple sources so far and i can't seem to figure out why pygame wont grab events to unpause in my pause function.

```
def pause():
    paused = True

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            elif event == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    paused = False
```

Keep in mind that this is nested in another while loop that's running the game, the function is called, gets stuck into an infinite loop, but can't detect key press to escape even with get keys function. Anybody got answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) returns a list of  [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) objects. You have to test if the `type` attribute of the `event` is `pygame.KEYDOWN`:

<s>`elif event == pygame.KEYDOWN:`</s>

```py
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

---

```py
def pause():
    paused = True

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    paused = False
```